# How to close mysql connection in AWS lambda with express js?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to close Mysql database connection in AWS lambda function which is using aws-serverless-express.

```
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host     : 'localhost',
      user     : 'me',
      password : 'secret',
      database : 'my_db'
    });

    connection.connect();

    connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error) throw error;
    });

    connection.end();
}
```

But I'm getting '**Error: Quit inactivity timeout**', How to fix this error in AWS lambda express?

Comment: This is asynchronous JavaScript, yes? It looks like you may be attempting to end the connection before the query completes.

Comment: @jarmod, Actually I have tried to put connection end inside query block but it's works first time but if I will make a request again after few seconds get 'Quit inactivity timeout' error.

Comment: OK, so you have two problems - the location of your call to connection.end(), and whatever is causing "Quit inactivity timeout". The web has a number of reports of the latter which may help.

Comment: Actually if I remove connection.end(); then code works proper but it's create a new connection everytime and I think those connections will be closed mysql after sometime, but If I want to close the connection once code done with the database operation, but with end connection getting 'Quit inactivity timeout' after first request.

Comment: Generally speaking, you want to create a connection pool outside of your event handler so that connections can be reused by subsequent Lambda invocations.

Comment: But what will be happen if there are more than 1000 users try to access lambda function at same time?

Comment: Move `connection.end()` *inside* the callback from the query.

Comment: I agree with above comments, move connection.end() to be inside of query. Also, make sure "var connection" is not in the global scope because you may have issues caused by different invocations trying to access the same var (in your case overwriting the `connection` var or the first lambda closing it while the second lambda is still querying). You say it errors if done twice within a few seconds. If you wait maybe 20 seconds between invocations you you get the errors? Does first or second invocation give error? Try using const or let and make sure the var is declared inside of index.handler.

Comment: @Jim, actually getting that error after second invocations. And Also I tried to move connection.end() inside of query but getting same error message.

Comment: @user3482441 That's what I thought would happen. Try my suggestions or post the whole file for your lambda function.

Comment: @jarmod, Could you please suggest me best practice to create a connection and close it. Like if there are concurrent 1000 connections then which option is best for it. 'createpool' OR 'createconnection' ?

Comment: Which MySQL node package are you using here? Is it mysqljs/mysql?

Comment: @jarmod, I'm using 'mysql' node package. https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql

Comment: @jarmod, Could you please suggest me the best practice to create and close connection in lambda aws, Is it proper to create a pool connection and once we done with sql query then release the connection.

Comment: Given your use case (potentially 1000 simultaneous Lambdas), I would think it best to create/destroy individual connections per invocation (so have all code inside the handler function). But you'd still need to fix the 'Quit inactivity timeout' issue (I would investigate that with the authors of the node package you're using). You're still going to have a problem of too many simultaneous connections to the DB requiring more sophisticated error handling in your Lambda or a different workflow (e.g. Lambdas queue messages then another process takes messages off queue and interacts with DB).

Comment: And other ideas: https://www.jeremydaly.com/manage-rds-connections-aws-lambda/

Comment: @jarmod, Actually I have research bit and found that, it would be good to use pool connection outside of handler function because it's cache and reuse by subsequent Lambda invocations. even if there are 1000 simultaneous connection and connection limit is 100 then code will serve 100 connection a time but rest 900 will be in queue. So code will not break.
Please correct me if I'm wrong, and really thanks for reply on my question.

Comment: you can check this post: https://blog.spotinst.com/2017/11/19/best-practices-serverless-connection-pooling-database/

Comment: also check this:https://codeforgeek.com/2015/01/nodejs-mysql-tutorial/

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, Could you please suggest that whether to use connection pooling in AWS lambda is good or not?
Or need to create/destroy individual connections per invocation?